# Trying to access class in python to retrieve if existing customer

Tags: python

I am new to Python
Using this code to create customer information. I then want to access this when i  add an order and link it with customer details.

So what i want is

1. Add New customer ( works through class for customer
2. Add New order - Type in customer name, it should retrieve all customer details and add to order.

Would appreciate help!!!

This the way i creat a new customer

## GET NEW CUSTOMER INFORMATION COLLECTED

```
  #  GET NEW CUSTOMER INFORMATION COLLECTED
```

```
#  GET NEW CUSTOMER INFORMATION COLLECTED

class Shop:
    def __init__(self, name, owner, location, tel , rating):
        self.name = name
        self.owner = owner
        self.location = location
        self.tel = tel
        self.rating = rating
​
    def getValues(self):
        return self.name + " " + self.owner + " " + self.location + " " + self.tel + " " + self.rating
​
    def Display(self):
        print("Invetory Unit: Shop \n Name: " + self.name + "\n Owner: " + self.owner + "\n location " + self.location + "\n Tel " + self.tel + " \n Rating :" + self.rating)
​
class Boutique(Shop):
    def __init__(self, Name, Owner,Location,Tel,Rating,yrsopen):
        Shop.__init__(self,Name, Owcocner,Location,Tel,Rating)
        self.yrsopen = yrsopen
​
    def GetBoutique(self):
        return self.getValues() + ", " + self.yrsopen
​
    def Display(self):
        print("Invetory Unit: Car \n Name: "+ self.name + "\n Owner: " + self.owner+ "\n location " + self.location+ "\n Tel " + self.tel +" \n Rating :" + self.rating + " \n Yrs open :" + self.yrsopen)
​
def main():
    shop_list = []
    shop_list.append(Boutique("Coco", "Jen", "Listowel", "0845555", "A", "20"))
    shop_list.append(Boutique("Sernena", "Joan", "Sansymount", "0863689", "B", "15"))
    
    newShop = "Y"
    while newShop == "Y":
        print('Input Shop Details')
        Name = input('Shop Name: ')
        Owner = input('Owner: ')
        Location = input('Location: ')
        Tel = input('Tel: ')
        Rating = input('Rating: ')
        yrsopen = input('Yrs Open: ')
​
        shop_list.append(Boutique(Name, Owner,Location,Tel,Rating,yrsopen))
        
        newShop = input('Add another Shop? (Y/N) ')          
    
    for shop in shop_list:
        print(shop.GetBoutique())
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your requirements correctly this should work as such. It asks if you want to add a new customer or add an order for existing customers. If you add an order it asks for the `Owner?` name in the customers list and if it is found it adds that Customers information into the `order_list` list and in the end after you exit it prints both `Customer List` and `Order List`.

```py
class Shop:
    def __init__(self, name, owner, location, tel , rating):
        self.name = name
        self.owner = owner
        self.location = location
        self.tel = tel
        self.rating = rating

    def getValues(self):
        return self.name + ' ' + self.owner + ' ' + self.location + ' ' + self.tel + ' ' + self.rating + ', ' + self.yrsopen

    def Display(self):
        print('Inventory Unit: Shop \n Name: ' + self.name + '\n Owner: ' + self.owner + '\n location ' + self.location + '\n Tel ' + self.tel + ' \n Rating :' + self.rating)


class Boutique(Shop):
    def __init__(self, Name, Owner, Location, Tel, Rating, yrsopen):
        Shop.__init__(self, Name, Owner, Location, Tel, Rating)
        self.yrsopen = yrsopen

    def GetBoutique(self):
        return self.getValues()

def addOrder(shop_list):
    order_list = []
    search_again = 'Y'
    while search_again.capitalize() == 'Y':
        owner_name = input('Enter the name of the owner to search for: ')
        found_customer = False
        for shop in shop_list:
            if shop.owner == owner_name:
                order_list.append(shop)
                print('Customer found and has been added to orders list!')
                found_customer = True
        if not found_customer:
            print('Customer not found.')
        search_again = input('Do you want to search again? (Y/N): ')
    return order_list


def addNewCustomer(shop_list):
    new_customer = 'Y'
    while new_customer.capitalize() == 'Y':
        print('Input Shop Details')
        Name = input('Shop Name: ')
        Owner = input('Owner: ')
        Location = input('Location: ')
        Tel = input('Tel: ')
        Rating = input('Rating: ')
        yrsopen = input('Yrs Open: ')
        shop_list.append(Boutique(Name, Owner, Location, Tel, Rating, yrsopen))
        new_customer = input('Add another Customer? (Y/N):')
    return shop_list

def main():
    shop_list = []
    order_list= []
    shop_list.append(Boutique('Coco', 'Jen', 'Listowel', '0845555', 'A', '20'))
    shop_list.append(Boutique('Sernena', 'Joan', 'Sansymount', '0863689', 'B', '15'))
    
    while True:
        print("[+] 1 for Adding a new customer")
        print("[+] 2 for Add a new order for a customer")
        print("[-] 3 for Exit")
        choice = input('Choose mode: ')
        if choice == '1':
            shop_list = addNewCustomer(shop_list)
        elif choice == '2':
            order_list = addOrder(shop_list)

        elif choice == '3':
            print('\nCustomer List:')
            for shop in shop_list:
                print(shop.GetBoutique())
            if not shop_list:
                print('Empty!')

            print('\nOrder List:')
            for shop in order_list:
                print(shop.getValues())
            if not order_list:
                print('Empty!')
            break
        else:
            print('Invalid input. Try again.')
            continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Let me know if you meant something else

Comment: @DonGormley Great, then you can mark this as the answer. Let me know if you need any more help. happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that, you want to add new customers using Customer class (that I assume you already have made) and then you want to add an order based on customer name and the code should automatically retrieve the customer details.

To create new customers, you should store the created object inside a list

```
list = []
c = Customer(fname, lname, age .... xyz args)
list.append( c )
```

Now, whenever you want want to add a new order ? you can do something like this

```
nameToLookFor = "alice"
customerFound = False
for customber in list:
    if customer.getName() == nameToLoofFor:
         # now create an order class object and obtain the customer 
         # details using customer.getDetails()
         customerFound = True
if not customerFound:
    # customer not found / does not exist
```

**Edit #1**

Looks like customer details are being stored inside the "Boutique" class and there is no need to make a Customer class (which I assumed you had when I answered this question)

What you can do is, create a method called .getName() inside the boutique class something like this

```py
def Boutique():
    # keep your existing functions 
    def getName(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Thanks for reply i now get : below when i runshop_list = []
shop_list.append(Boutique("Coco", "Jen", "Listowel", "0845555", "A", "20"))
shop_list.append(Boutique("Sernena", "Joan", "Sansymount", "0863689", "B", "15"))

105 customerFound = False
    106 for customer in shop_list:
--> 107     if customer.getName() == shopname_entry:

AttributeError: 'Boutique' object has no attribute 'getName'

Comment: Ayush could help with a problem i have accessing the customers name.  When customer is found i want to display his full details. Can you help